# How to read different linear algebra notations

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I always get confused by different notations in linear algebra. For example, I find that this is clear and I can follow everything that is going on by the rules of matrix multiplication

$$
A = U \Sigma V^T
$$

But sometimes I see a notation like this...

$$
A = U \Sigma V^T = u_1 \sigma_1 v^T_1 + u_1 \sigma_1v^T_1 + ... + u_r \sigma_r v^T_r
$$

and I find it really confusing to understand by looking because its not immediately obvious to me if the subscripts are columns or rows and if the result of these additions are vectors or matrices... How can I read the notation on the right of this equation?

Even worse is the summation notation which makes it even harder to see and would look something like this...

$$
A_{ij} = \sum \sum \sum \text{confusing}_{ij} \text{subscript}_{ji} \text{hell}_{ijk}
$$

Comment: In this notation, the vectors $u_i$ and $v_j$ are column vectors and $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ are scalars. Each summand is then an $n\times 1$ vector, times a scalar, times the transpose of an $n\times 1$ (and hence a $1\times n$ vector). Thus, each summand is $n\times n$.

Comment: are single subscripts on vectors always columns?

Comment: No. The point here is that these vectors are “column vectors”, that is, you think of them as $n\times 1$ vectors, rather than as “row vectors. E.g., $\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\right)$, instead of $(a,b)$. But this is typical when you have matrices act by multiplying on the left. Indices just mean a family of vectors.

Comment: right, but my point is that if you have a different multiplication without the right matrix being transposed, then $AB = a_1b_1 + ...$ would be multiplying a column vector of $A$ which is $a_1$ by a row vector of $B$ which is $b_1$ so the subscripts are not always columns or rows, but I have to deduce the meaning based on the position of the matrices, right?

Comment: You deduce the meaning based on the equation. Here, they cannot represent rows because then the left hand side would be a matrix but the right hand side would be a scalar. There is no universal notation for “this is a row” and “this is a column”. That said, it is bad notation to use too similar a notation to mean two different things in the same expression so anyone who wrote what you wrote in the above comment, without a clear and explicit statement that said something like “where $a_i$ is the $i$th `blah` of $A$ sand $b_j$ is the $j$th `blah` of $B$” should be severely beaten.

Comment: you said two things that seem to be contradictory. You said "you deduce meaning based on the equation" but then you said "it is bad notation to use similar notation to mean two different things in the same expression." My original question used the SVD which uses $V^T$, so assuming that the $V$ was not transposed then it would be the same as my $AB$ example and therefore bad notation, right? How would you suggest changing my example or the formula in my original question?

Comment: In your original equation, both $u_i$ and $v_i$ are column vectors. The fact that you have it transposed is **precisely** what makes it so that you are always talking about column vectors and not sometimes column vectors and sometimes row vectors. So, no, I did not say two things that are or seem contradictory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97130/discussion-between-deltaskelta-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: Sorry, I don’t do chat.

Comment: then is the only way to make my above $AB$ example use proper notation to include a qualifier that says $a_1$ is a column vector and $b_1$ is a row vector? or is there a way to do it with just the notation alone?

Comment: There is no absolute “proper notation”; what there is is good notation, understandable notation, bad notation, and confusing notation. What you wrote with $AB$ is bad and confusing. What you quote is understandable and reasonable, because the $u_i$ and the $v_i$ are either *all* columns, or *all* rows, and only one of the interpretations makes the equations sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the SVD, you can read it as

$$ A = U \Sigma V^{T} = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \sigma_{i} u_{i} v_{i}^{T} $$

as a matrix $A$ is actually the sum of $r$ rank $1$ matrices $u_{i}v_{i}^{T}$ which have a scaling factor of $\sigma_{i}$.

The matrix $u_{i}v_{i}^{T}$ is the matrix generated as the outer product of the two vectors $u_{i} , v_{i}$

Comment: In some contexts, the $\mathbf u\mathbf v^\top$ construction would be called an "outer product"; thus, you can say that the SVD expresses any matrix as a weighted sum of outer products.